# R in Teradata - How can user execute his R code on Teradata Vantage?

Tags: python, r, teradata

What does Teradata offer for executing R code against Vantage platform? 
Are there any tutorials available?

Comment: This is outside the scope of a stack overflow question. You would perhaps find more success looking for an answer with an internet search.

Answer (score 2):

Using R and Python with Vantage | Part 1: Overview: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjgFWBc2kTM

**A: Client-side options**

The “tdplyr” R add-on library (freely available at downloads.teradata.com) builds on the “dplyr” foundation specifically for interaction with Vantage servers. In addition to the functions provided by "dplyr" it also provides R wrappers for about 100+ analytic functions in the newly introduced Machine Learning Engine (MLE) component of Vantage systems, and 9 analytic functions in the Advanced SQL Engine (ASQLE; the former Teradata Database) component of Vantage systems. The Teradata R package for clients, “tdplyr”, thus enables both data wrangling and seamless in-database analytics with data straight from the database, thereby relieving customers from having to move any data from the database to the client and back.

"tdplyr" documentation can be found at: 
https://docs.teradata.com/reader/EZAbQ2BX~vKBrWDQ3v7fPQ/qPSuQaTN2CYD~KUvLxY7mg.

Analytics with “tdplyr” are demonstrated in part 2 of the “R and Python with Vantage” TechBytes series at: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DCbTpWSLJI

**B: In-nodes options**

Teradata also offers in-nodes solutions for R users via the SCRIPT Table Operator (STO; since Teradata Database v.15.00) and the ExecR Table Operator (ExecR; since Teradata Database v.15.10). Both approaches enable users to bring their R scripts and execute them natively in-database on R interpreter instances that run on each ASQLE node. Because of the nature of the database architecture, this approach is most appropriate and effective for:

a) model scoring tasks, whereby an R script only needs one row of data as input to score it with a given model; for this reason, the scoring task takes place across all nodes extremely efficiently in what is known as an “embarrassingly parallel” task.

b) fitting multiple models by partitioning a data table by some feature; in this scenario, each AMP (ASQLE database processing unit) processes all data of a single partition, and this results in simultaneous fitting of all models in a parallel fashion.

A more complicated scenario is when the user wishes to fit a model with data from across the entire database; typically, these tasks involve operations in two steps, where the first step is executing a script that receives partial results from each AMP (“mapping” phase), and in the second step a second script needs to consume these partial answers to yield the final result (“reduce” phase). This approach puts the programming onus on the user (unlike the MLE analytic functions that perform this sequence of steps seamlessly to the user when fitting models from a client).
Memory processing limit for ExecR is 3.5 GB per AMP.

**B.1: ExecR**

Users can bring their R scripts directly into ExecR, yet the data input and output parts where the script interacts with the database need suitable modification by using the so-called FNC functions in ExecR. These are Teradata-built R functions that carry these data and metadata transfer tasks. A detailed ExecR documentation can be found at:

https://docs.teradata.com/reader/T5QsmcznbJo1bHmZT2KnFw/EabyaGA8DZhLIXy~uhzvsA

**B.2: SCRIPT**

SCRIPT Table Operator (STO): In this approach, the script receives data from a single table via the script’s standard input, needs to interpret the input data types correctly for R, and sends the results to the database (or the SQL interface) via the script’s standard output. Therefore, in this approach, the R script data input and output segments need to be composed accordingly prior to uploading the script to the database and executing it via the STO. Other than this, an instance of the script runs exactly on an R interpreter on each database AMP as it would run on a client.